# Рекурсия для подсчета файлов в папках и подпапках

Tags: java, многопоточность, поиск, рекурсия

Добрый день, я недавно начал осваивать программирование.
Задача состоит в следующем: Создать класс,который в потоке будет подсчитывать кол-во файлов в заданной директории и поддиректориях, и записать их в файл.
Никак не могу разобраться, как же написать подобную рекурсию в потоке, есть пример кода, но он считывает только количество файлов в одной директории(и то через костыль(. Поток создаю в main, через Executors.

```
public class MatchCounter implements Runnable {

public MatchCounter(String dir) {this.dir = dir;}

String dir;

public String getDir() {return dir;}

@Override
public void run() {
    File listFile = new File( getDir() );
    File exportFiles[] = listFile.listFiles( );
    String[] names = new String[exportFiles.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i] = exportFiles[i].getName( );
        try {
            sleep( 5 );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }
    int s = exportFiles.length;
    Integer.toString( s );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет именно о реализации с несколькими потоками, то можно попробовать что-то типа:

```
package com.stackoverflow.filessearcher;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

/**
 * Executable класс позволяющий найти все существующие файлы в заданной папке и подпапках, используя рекурсивный метод
 * {@link FilesAmountCalculator#iterateThroughTheFolder(File[], FileWriter)}.
 * <p/>
 * Имя папки, в которой должен быть осуществлен поиск должен передаваться параметром, например,
 * <code>java FilesAmountCalculator D:\example</code>. В случае если указанной папки не существует будет выбрашено исклю-
 * чение <code>Parameter is not a folder. Folder path should be inserted</code>.
 * <p/>
 * Запись в файл осуществляется в отдельных потоках, количество которых соответсвует количеству подпапок. Таким образом
 * запись имени файла из определенной подпапки будет осуществляться в отельном потоке. Эффективность данного подхода
 * сомнительна, поскольку теория говорит о том, что запись в файл лучше делать линейно.
 * </p>
 * В конечном итоге программа выводит количество найденных файлов.
 */
public class FilesAmountCalculator {
    public static final String OUTPUTFILE = "output";
    static int amountOfFiles;

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        File directory = new File(args[0]);
        if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Parameter is not a folder. Folder path should be inserted");
        }

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(OUTPUTFILE, false);
        File[] folderHierarchy = directory.listFiles();

        iterateThroughTheFolder(folderHierarchy, fileWriter);

        System.out.println("Amount of files:" + amountOfFiles);
        fileWriter.close();
    }

    /**
     * Рекурсивный метод, который запускает отдельный поток для каждой из подпапок, находящихся в папке поиска. В случае
     * работы с файлом - он будет записан, в случае с папкой - метод вызовет сам себя и передаст в качестве параметра
     * название поддирректории.
     *
     * @param directory  список файлов в дирректории
     * @param fileWriter используется для записи в файл
     */
    public static void iterateThroughTheFolder(File[] directory, FileWriter fileWriter) {

        FileWriterThread fileWriterThread = new FileWriterThread(directory, fileWriter);
        fileWriterThread.run();
    }

    /**
     * Внутренний класс, реализующий работу потока для обработки файлов из выбранной поддиректории, которые передаются
     * в качестве параметра внутри конструктора.
     * </p>
     * Вся работа происходит в переопределенном методе {@link Thread#run()}, который осуществляет итерацию по файлам и
     * записывает их имена в файл.
     */
    private static class FileWriterThread extends Thread {
        private File[] folderHierarchy;
        private FileWriter fileWriter;

        private FileWriterThread(File[] folderHierarchy, FileWriter fileWriter) {
            this.folderHierarchy = folderHierarchy;
            this.fileWriter = fileWriter;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (File file : folderHierarchy) {
                try {
                    write(file);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Метод записывает название файлы в результирующий файл или рекурсивно вызывает метод
         * {@link FilesAmountCalculator#iterateThroughTheFolder(File[], FileWriter)}. В случае работы с папкой
         * <code>listFiles</code> метод может вернуть <code>null</code> в случае если нет привилегий для ее просмотра.
         *
         * @param file название папки или определенного файла
         * @throws IOException будет выброшено в случае проблем записи в файл
         */
        private synchronized void write(File file) throws IOException {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                File[] directory = file.listFiles();

                // в случае "закрытой" папки вернуть управление
                if (directory == null) {
                    return;
                }

                // рекурсивный вызов метода
                iterateThroughTheFolder(directory, fileWriter);
            } else {
                amountOfFiles++;
                fileWriter.write(file.getName() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь комментарии помогут лучше понять утилиту. Ну и все же многопоточная запись - сомнительное удовольствие. Возможно, Вы имели в виду что-то другое под "в потоке будет подсчитывать".

Comment: спасибо, помогло, разобрался!